# Ubuntu freezes and stop working after update 18.04 (Problem graphic card AMD, how to disable)

Tags: 18.04, graphics, freeze, amd-graphics

I have a problem after updating Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04.
First, I have to say my computer is an old HP Notebook with switchable graphics: one Intel integrated and an AMD graphic card.

The good one, the AMD no long work since one year or so. So I use the Open Gl who picked Ubuntu to run.

When i updated all worked fine, but after a restart Ubuntu used the AMD resulting in instant freeze and I can't use Ubuntu at all now.

So, my question is, how can I disable the AMD card? 
I tried searching in the BIOS for a chance to disable it, but all I can do is change the mode the switchable graphics work,fixed or dinamic, which does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this steps:

```
lsmod | grep radeon
```

OR

```
lsmod | grep amd
```

Select most relevant driver from list and copy it (first column).

Then edit file:

```
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and add this driver\device name to this file like:

```
# Disable my AMD graphic card
amd_card   # - paste module name you copied before
```

Reboot.

Comment: S_Flash thanks for the answer, I tried lsmod | grep amd but got 0 results When I tried lsmod | grep radeon got as first result: radeon 1470464 1

How do I find and edit this?

PD: The Unity desktop seems to work, but not the new Gnome desktop

Comment: @Alex sure, you need do it for radeon. AMD was just example how to find driver by part of name. I cant check it because use nvidea. But if Unity work for you you can chenge graphic driver in GUI using **Software & Updates** -> **Additional Drivers** (this way more accurate like for me).